# Escaping in wget bash command

Tags: bash, ubuntu, escaping, wget

`wget -q -T 60 --retry-connrefused -t 5 --waitretry=60 --user=ftp2.company.com|company2013 --password=!company2013 -N -P data/parser/company/ ftp://ftp2.company.com/Production/somedata.zip`

I'm having trouble with this command, because the password contains an exclamation mark. I tried escaping with \, tried single quotes, and it either gives the output:

`wget: missing URL`

or

`bash: !company2013: event not found`

This is really demotivating...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this part needs to be quoted to prevent it from being seen as a pipe to another command.

```
--user='ftp2.company.com|company2013'
```

And this one too to prevent history expansion with !:

```
--password='!company2013'
```

Final:

```
wget -q -T 60 --retry-connrefused -t 5 --waitretry=60 --user='ftp2.company.com|company2013' --password='!company2013' -N -P data/parser/company/ ftp://ftp2.company.com/Production/somedata.zip
```

And it's also a good idea to quote the other parts if on later time they have spaces:

```
wget -q -T 60 --retry-connrefused -t 5 --waitretry=60 --user='ftp2.company.com|company2013' --password='!company2013' -N -P "data/parser/company/" "ftp://ftp2.company.com/Production/somedata.zip"
```

Comment: Wow. That was so dumb, I'm ashamed. Thank You for the quick answer!I tried everything with the password part, never thought about the username.