# Cannot open some URLs using wget

Tags: linux, wget

I'm using wget (on Linux) to get this website - http://web.ifzq.gtimg.cn/appstock/app/fqkline/get?_var=kline_dayqfq2014&param=sh600000,day,2014-01-01,2015-12-31,640,qfq&r=0.49504152244266863 ,
but it seems to be timeout,

Cause there is & symbol in the url, so I saved the url to a file (url.txt) and the use the query:

```
wget -i url.txt
```

and information as follows:

```
Resolving web.ifzq.gtimg.cn (web.ifzq.gtimg.cn)... 183.232.125.158

Connecting to web.ifzq.gtimg.cn (web.ifzq.gtimg.cn)|183.232.125.158|:80... failed: Connection timed out.

Retrying.
```

Also, I can use this machine to access other websites like https://github.com/, so it may not be the network problem.
And I've tried to use the same commond on other linux machine, it works out fine, I can successfully download the page.

It's NOT because of special symbols. I've tried this url  http://web.ifzq.gtimg.cn/appstock/app/fqkline on both machine, and still one cannot work while the other works out fine.

So what may be the problem?
Thanks for answer!

Comment: What have you tried, what was exactly your command you used? It works for me if I quote url in `"`. Maybe the `&` is making trouble which means starting a subprocess in linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why wget ignores query string in the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474482/why-wget-ignores-query-string-in-the-url)

Comment: I use the same command 'wget http://web.ifzq.gtimg.cn/appstock/app/fqkline/get?_var=kline_dayqfq2014&param=sh600000,day,2014-01-01,2015-12-31,640,qfq&r=0.49504152244266863' on both of my machine, and one of them worked but the other time out

Comment: Can you provide the `exact command` you used in the question, please? This would be very nice and then we can help you accurately.

Comment: ?  ... 2014&param ... qfq&r=

Comment: Oh...sorry I missed that. I will try the solution first

Comment: [How can I encode an url for wget?](https://superuser.com/q/728150/173513), [wget escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37989784/608639), [Escaping in wget bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18120626/608639), [URL encoding a string in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11876353/608639), etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to someone who mentioned that this connection time out may because of the machine is banned by this particular website, though this answer has been deleted, but I think it's right.

If you see the same error codes like discribed in the question and want to find out if you are banned, maybe you can try ping to this website.

If you can successfully ping to this website, then you are probably banned by this website.